# Azure Search on Central India Region

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am building an application which uses the following Azure Services.

- Azure App Service : To Host the FrontEnd and BackEnd Web Apps
- Azure SQL Database : To store the structured data
- Azure Cosmos DB : To store the JSON Data
- Azure Storage : To store the images, files, videos as blobs

All these services will run in Central India Region. Will I be able to use Azure Search on these services like SQL DB, CosmosDB (MongoDB API) & Storage (Blobs and Files)? During a Bootcamp, last week, an MVP said that the Azure Search feature works only in West US region.

Thanks,

Manoj Kumar

Answer (score 2):

Azure Search is generally available in Central India and many others regions (I am using it in West Europe).

Have a look [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=search&regions=all) for more information on azure services availability.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/global-infrastructure/services/?products=search&regions=central-india,south-india,west-india, it seems Azure Search is available in Central India however when I tried to create a search account in that region using portal, I was not able to do so.

Having said that, Azure Search should still work as it uses HTTP based REST API. Considering how you end up using Azure Search, you might expect some latency based on where your users are based.